# Error creating Windows virtual machine on Google Cloud: Not included with the free trial

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, gcloud, billing

I'm trying to create a virtual machine on Google Cloud using the following command:

```
gcloud compute instances create my-server-1 \
    --zone=europe-west3-b \
    --machine-type=n1-standard-16 \
    --accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-t4-vws,count=1 \
    --maintenance-policy="TERMINATE" \
    --image-project=windows-cloud \
    --image-family=windows-2019 \
    --boot-disk-size=200 \
    --network=default
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Windows VM instances are not included with the free trial. To use them, first enable billing on your account. You'll still be able to apply your free trial credits to eligible products and services.
```

I've verified that billing is enabled for my project, and I've checked the billing account with the following commands:

```
myaccount@cloudshell:~ (myproject)$ gcloud beta billing projects describe myproject
billingAccountName: billingAccounts/0X0X0X-0X0X0X-0X0X0X
billingEnabled: true
name: projects/myproject/billingInfo
projectId: myproject
```

```
myaccount@cloudshell:~ (myproject)$ gcloud beta billing accounts describe 0X0X0X-0X0X0X-0X0X0X
displayName: My Billing Account
masterBillingAccount: ''
name: billingAccounts/0X0X0X-0X0X0X-0X0X0X
open: true
```

Both commands show that billing is enabled. I also have a valid payment method associated with my Google Cloud account.

Can anyone help me understand why I'm still getting this error? Is there something else I need to do to create a Windows virtual machine on Google Cloud?

Comment: Refer to Official Google Cloud [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#free_trial) for info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Windows Server images aren't included in the Free Trial**. [Upgrade to a paid Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade).

Under a free version billing account, there are certain limitations with resources such as windows resources, GPU and also in increasing certain quotas.

Since you have a [90-day, $300 Free Trial offer](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features#free-trial), when you upgrade to a paid account, it will be carried over to your paid account and cover the charges until it gets consumed but under a paid account you will be automatically be charged once the free credits are consumed.

To activate these resources and use all the resources of Google Cloud, you need to enable an account which means **you need to upgrade to a paid account**.